# How to make certain command line arguments run by default for a program in linux?

Tags: bash, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, httpserver

So I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL2, and using the npm http-server (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

But, by default it enables caching, so I preferably want to disable caching by default. I know I can do it using

```
http-server -c-1
```

But is there any way to make that the default behaviour of `http-server`? So when I just run `http-server`, caching is disabled by default. I would like to not use aliasing to achieve this, instead using a bash script. I saw (in a course which had a codespace setup), that this was achieved by using a bash script, and whenever I ran `which http-server`, it would return something like `/opt/name_conf/bin/http-server`, which running `http-server` on my setup gives `/usr/bin/http-server`

How do I achieve the config that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/http-server -c-1 "$@"
```

Name it `http-server` and make it executable and it must appear in a directory **earlier** in your PATH than the "real http-server.

I would use a shell function: add this to your ~/.bashrc

```sh
http-server() {
    command http-server -c-1 "$@"
}
```

In this case, you don't need to hardcode the full path to the real http-server: the `command` keyword ensures that the function does not call itself in an endless recursion.

Comment: I did this. But still, when running `which http-server`, it shows the path where the "real http-server" is located

How do I fix this?

Comment: Normally, I keep such 'overrides' in `~/bin` and keep `~/bin` as the first path in `$PATH`.

Comment: "I did this." You did what? I offered you 2 solutions. If you chose the function, yes `which http-server` will still show the real one. Use `type -a http-server` to let the shell show you what it's going to pick up first.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an alias:

```
alias http-server="http-server -c-1"
```

This will be valid for the current shell session.

If you want to make this persistent for all your future shell sessions, add it to your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc` etc.